# In what story do annoying aliens plant hollyhocks in the Sahara?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

What is the name of the story in which the following happens?

Aliens make contact and humans are awestruck/fearful/excited, but as they get to know the them, the aliens turn out to be annoying and boorish. The aliens flatly declare the hollyhock is the most beautiful flower--no ifs, ands, or buts, and demonstrate their technical prowess by greening the Sahara...with hollyhocks. (Maybe they green the Sahara first--with hollyhocks--and explain why hollyhocks with the declaration of their ultimate beauty.)

In the end, humans make use of the aliens' advanced technology to travel to other planets in order to escape the vapid aliens who have now settled on earth.

I read this story in the 1980s or so, but it may be from much earlier.

Comment: ...I have to admit, that's an interesting approach to colonization and conquest. Just move in "peacefully" and then gentrify the entire area until the original inhabitants -- at least, those who can afford to -- move elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't it be no ifs, ands, or buds?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's "[The Aliens Who Knew, I Mean, Everything](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57410)" by George Alec Effinger.

> So we thanked the nuhp for a Namibia full of hollyhocks...

It ends

> All through the galaxy, the nuhp are considered the messengers of peace...But if the nuhp started moving in down the block, we'd be packed and on our way somewhere else by morning.

Comment: thanks very much!

Comment: @Schneb You're welcome! Funny story.

Comment: Oddly, though - Namibia is nowhere near the Sahara, it's on the other end of Africa.  Namibia has its own unconnected desert, the [Namib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namib).  Was this author error?  Or did the OP just misremember that detail?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it actually says that "we..stopped them before they did the same thing to the Sahara, the Mojave, and the Gobi."

Comment: Maybe the mistake is mine? In saying they 'greened the Sahara' did I remember the wrong desert?

Comment: @Schneb no worries, you gave enough info to id the story, that's what counts.

Answer (score 10):

This is "[The Aliens Who Knew, I Mean, Everything](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57410)" by George Alec Effinger

> He brought back some
> wonderful slides: the vast desert had
> been turned into a botanical miracle.
> There were miles and miles of flowering plants now, instead of the monotonous dead sand and gravel sea.
> Of course, the immense garden contained nothing but hollyhocks, many
> millions of hollyhocks. I mentioned
> to Pleen that the people of Earth had
> been hoping for a little more in the
> way of variety, and something just a
> trifle more practical, too.
>
> “What do you mean, ‘practical?'" he asked.
>
> “You know," I said, “food."
>
> “Don’t worry about food," said Pleen. “We're going to take care of hunger pretty soon.”
>
> “Good, good. But hollyhocks?"
>
> “What’s wrong with hollyhocks?"
>
> “Nothing," I admitted.
>
> “Hollyhocks are the single prettiest flower grown on Earth."